# Ubuntu Studio 20.04 desktop environment fails to load

Tags: gnome-shell, desktop-environments

I have been using Ubuntu Studio 20.04 pretty much since the stable version got out (clean installation on SSD drive, no dual booting or anything like that). Not long after (maybe a month?) I started having this problem where after logging in (using the shipped-in gdm3 as display manager) the desktop environment wouldn't load properly showing me just a blank screen with the cursor in it and the fans would go nuts -which to me means that the CPU was working full-on but got stuck in some sort of loop-, forcing me to hard-poweroff the machine.

Booting in recovery mode, doing nothing while in it, and then continuing to normal boot seemed to work but I wouldn't get full graphics capabilities as the system loaded a generic graphics driver (llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits)). Since I work on graphics and video, this wasn't a good workaround.

Then I tried switching the display manager to lightdm (shooting blindly) and hey-ho, happy coincidence, it all started working, so I just kept using lightdm from then on. Now, however, the problem has returned and it doesn't matter which display manager I choose because the result is the same (though with lightdm I do get a wallpaper in the background).
The recovery mode work-around still works and I have done some updates over the last few days but I didn't notice anything because I don't usually power off the machine, so I'm not sure at which point the problem came back...

I am on Gnome 3.36.3, if that helps...

I don't know what tests to run. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After raking my brains for days on end I've finally figured out that it has something to do with gnome extensions. I've restarted the machine with and without extensions turned on several times and the test is conclusive: every single time I have extensions turned on the desktop would fail to load.

Now it's about figuring out whether it's one in particular, several working together or the whole extensions functionality, but at least now I have my machine back...

I hope this helps others who might find themselves in this pickle.